# ERROR: Value of type 'Byte' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of byte' in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, byte

Here I have saved PDF file in database by converting it into Bytes.
Database column holds type of varbinary(MAX)!

When i'm retrieving data from database and then converting it to PDF then it is showing me this error at line:

```
fileBytes = Convert.ToByte(dataset.Tables["tbl"].Rows[0][0])
```

My whole code is here:

```
Dim fileBytes As Byte()
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=desktop-stapg4d\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=renser;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim command As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "select file_content from files"
    command = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    command.Fill(dataset, "tbl")
    fileBytes = Convert.ToByte(dataset.Tables["tbl"].Rows[0][0])

    conn.Open()
```

Please help me friends.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please post your real code.  That will not compile.

Comment: Well, you definitely don't want to convert a PDF to a single byte.  Consider CType(yadayada, Byte())

Comment: @HansPassant , sorry but I'm not able to get you, will you plz explain it quite descriptive so that I can make the same in my code??
And I'm using Byte() (array) not a single byte??

Comment: #Hans Passant, sorry but I'm not able to get you, will you plz explain it quite descriptive so that I can make the same in my code??

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToByte` is a function that returns exactly one `Byte`, but `fileBytes` is declared as being an array of `Byte`, so the error message is quite clear, it can't convert the 1-byte result of `Convert.ToByte` to a many-bytes byte array.